# AWS Fargate ALB DNS not resolving

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, amazon-elb

I've built the below infrastructure for use with AWS Fargate.

The ECS manages containers in private subnets, with traffic routed to them through an  internet-facing ALB via public subnets.

Internet access to the containers in the private subnets is controlled via NAT Gateways.

I've created a git repo which demonstrates the problem at hand
https://github.com/GreenyMcDuff/aws-fargate-public

**Warning: It will cost you money to run this**

Requires Terraform v0.11.7 or greater

[image]

Here are the security group rules:

**alb-sg**

```
+----------------+----------+------+------------+
| Ingress/Egress | Protocol | Port |   Source   |
+----------------+----------+------+------------+
| Ingress        | TCP      | 80   | 0.0.0.0/0  |
| Egress         | All      | All  | 0.0.0.0/0  |
+----------------+----------+------+------------+
```

**ecs-tasks-sg**

```
+----------------+----------+---------+-----------+
| Ingress/Egress | Protocol |  Port   |  Source   |
+----------------+----------+---------+-----------+
| Ingress        | TCP      | 80      | 0.0.0.0/0 |
| Ingress        | TCP      | 1-65535 | alb-sg-id |
| Egress         | All      | All     | 0.0.0.0/0 |
+----------------+----------+---------+-----------+
```

And here are the route tables

**public route table**

```
+-------------+--------+
| Destination | Target |
+-------------+--------+
| 10.0.0.0/16 | local  |
| 0.0.0.0/0   | igw-id |
+-------------+--------+
```

**private route table**

```
+-------------+--------+
| Destination | Target |
+-------------+--------+
| 10.0.0.0/16 | local  |
| 0.0.0.0/0   | nat-id |
+-------------+--------+
```

So almost everything seems to be working.  The container I'm launching is the  `httpd:2.4` image from the docker hub.

- The image is downloaded successfully
- The container launches and enters a `RUNNING` state fine.
- The elb health check passes
- I've launched a windows EC2 instance in my public subnet, RDP'd to it, and browsed the containers ip in Internet Explorer and I get the page as expected

I'm working under the assumption that this is a routing or security-group problem because of the above points.

The problem is that when I try and browse the site, running on the container, by hitting the Application Load Balancers DNS name (`xxxx.AWS_REGION.elb.amazonaws.com`), I get a "This site can't be reached" error.

Any explanations on why this might be happening would be greatly received.

Please let me know if any more information would be helpful and I will do my best to provide it.